# How to get the URL for a selected document in a sharepoint framework extension spfx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-framework

How can I obtain the URL for a selected document in a sharepoint framework extension?

e.g. a friendly url or unique reference that a user can use to open the selected document;

```
https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/test/documents/mydocument.pdf
```

I'm trying to create a new item in the ECB menu 'Open in my application' that will get the url for selected document, insert a prefix, and pass the url to the browser;

```
    protocol-handler://MyPrefixhttps://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/test/documents/mydocument.pdf
```

I'm having difficulty obtaining the URL for the document using the sharepoint framework, I'm unsure if it's even possible. I've looked in the api reference for objects like sp-page-context but was unable to see any methods or properties that would return the URL for the selected document.

In the past this has been possible using Sharepoint Apps (e.g. [{SiteUrl}{ItemUrl}](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75801/sharepoint-app-get-path-of-selected-document)), but I don't believe these are compatible with Sharepoint Online. What would be the correct approach to achieve this in Sharepoint Online?

Useful references;

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/sharepoint

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/migrate-from-ecb-to-spfx-extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `.spItemUrl` property or `FileRef` to get the absolute URL of the document in a document library.

So modifying the example present in the link you have mentioned, modify your `onExecute` method as below to get the absolute URL of the document in the document library:

```
@override
  public onExecute(event: IListViewCommandSetExecuteEventParameters): void {
    switch (event.itemId) {
      case 'ShowDetails':

          //sharepoint doc lib url
          const documentServerRelativeUrl = event.selectedRows[0].getValueByName('FileRef');

          //form the absolute url
          const documentAbsUrl = "protocol-handler://MyPrefixhttps://" + `$https://mysite.sharepoint.com${documentServerRelativeUrl}`;

          //pass the documentAbsUrl to redirect code, something as below
          window.location.replace(documentAbsUrl);      
        break;  
      default:
        throw new Error('Unknown command');
    }
}
```

If however, you want to redirect a user so that it can be accessible outside of SharePoint as well without any authentication, use `.spItemUrl` as below:

```
@override
  public onExecute(event: IListViewCommandSetExecuteEventParameters): void {
    switch (event.itemId) {
      case 'ShowDetails':          
          //one drive absolute url which can be opened anonymously
          const documentUrl = event.selectedRows[0].getValueByName('.spItemUrl') + '&$select=@content.downloadUrl';

          const oneDriveUrl = "protocol-handler://MyPrefixhttps://" + documentUrl;

          //pass the oneDriveUrl to redirect code        
          window.location.replace(oneDriveUrl);
        break;  
      default:
        throw new Error('Unknown command');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping to find a call that would provide the an entire absolute url to the document, including the site.

e.g.

https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/Test/MyDocument.pdf

It appears such a call doesn't exist. The .spItemUrl is interesting, though I'm not sure if this type of URL will work with the application I'm passing the url to (it's a custom application that opens documents using WebDAV protocol)

It looks like parts of the URL can be obtained separately and pieced together to form the full URL.

e.g.

```
    //e.g. https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/Test
    const siteAbsUrl = this.context.pageContext.site.absoluteUrl;

    //e.g. /sites/Test
    const siteRelUrl = this.context.pageContext.site.serverRelativeUrl;

    //sites/Test/Shared Documents/MyDocument.pdf
    const docRelativeUrl :string = event.selectedRows[0].getValueByName('FileRef');

    //form the absolute url
    const absUrl = "my-protocol://PREFIX" + `${siteAbsUrl}` +`${docRelativeUrl.substr(siteRelUrl.length)}`;


    window.location.replace(`${absUrl}`);
```

It looks like this will work, though I'm still considering how best to handle spaces in the url and whether they should be url encoded as %20. e.g. .../Shared%20Documents/...