# How to get Share URL from command set?

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions, command-set, listviewcommandset

I am developing a command set & looking for a way to get the Share URL of selected documents. I have tried these to get other urls.

```
event.selectedRows.getValueByName('.spItemUrl');
event.selectedRows.getValueByName('FileRef');
```

But I want the URL look like below, which we will get something when we Share or Copy Link:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/:i:/s/Personal/EZtdo-T3MAtJldnaju5gtb4BBmXWDdNdljhdDywGBQJAgA?e=WYgQZ5
```

How to get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the Share URL, you can use any of the 3 approaches mentioned below:

**Option 1** - using `ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl`

You can make use the `ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl` to get the URL as below:

```
event.selectedRows.getValueByName('ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl');
```

**Option 2** - using `?web=1` query string parameter

Another thing you can do is append the `?web=1` query string parameter and form the absolute url of the file.

```
const absoluteUrl:string = this.context.pageContext.site.absoluteUrl;

const relativeUrl:string = this.context.pageContext.site.serverRelativeUrl;

const docRelativeUrl:string = event.selectedRows[0].getValueByName('FileRef');

const docShareUrl = `${absoluteUrl}${docRelativeUrl.substr(relativeUrl.length)}?web=1`;
```

However, both above approaches have the document opening in a preview or read mode. 
I have noticed that the OOTB Share or Copy command generates the URL and when opened, the document is in edit mode.

So, to open it in edit mode, you can use option 3.

**Option 3** - Open in edit mode

Here you need to form the url dynamically yourself as below:

The url format is:  `<Site URL>/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=<Doc URL>&action=edit`

```
const absoluteUrl:string = this.context.pageContext.site.absoluteUrl;

const docRelativeUrl:string = event.selectedRows[0].getValueByName('FileRef');

const docShareUrl = `${absoluteUrl}/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=${docRelativeUrl}&action=edit`;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know why 'ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl' is empty for me?

Comment: Could be the case that its not an Office document. I tested this with docx, xlsx and pptx files and it worked.

Comment: I see why you are hardcoding format in option 3. getValueByName('.spItemUrl') + '&$select=webUrl' is not working..

Comment: Sorry Arun didnt get your point. Which one is not working ? Couldn't spot `getValueByName('.spItemUrl') ` in the answer :)  Safest and best option IMHO would be option 2. Some of our clients dont like stuff opening in edit mode, so i usually use option 2 to open in read mode.

Comment: Never mind, I was reading your [another answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/236717/72613), you use "&$select=@content.downloadUrl" & I thought similarly "webUrl" can be used instead of hardcoded "...WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=.." like in option 3.. anyway thanks for assistance..